# Log cat Not Showing in android studio

Tags: android-studio, logcat

[image]
Log cat not getting showed , its showing adb logs....I thing we should change logcat|ADBlogs mode to Devices|LogCat

Can any one help me out how to change this mode that can display LogCat.

Comment: chk https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: I resolved the issue , by right click on "ADB logs" and close the ADB logs :)
BTW @Shubhalaxmi Nayak  thanx for responding